Pi 5 wired ethernet has 90% ping failure using old 10 Mbps switch
I am using a new Pi 5 and OS: 2024-11-19-raspios-bookworm-arm64.img. I cannot reliably ping on my local wired network or to the internet.I get >80% packet loss.
My wired network uses an old 10  Mbps switch, which works fine for all my other devices and connections. However if I bypass the 10 Mbps switch direct to the upstream 100Mbps router, network access is OK with no ping packet loss. If I use the wireless lan access point, which is connected to the 100 Mbps router, network access is also fine.
I deduce that there is a problem with the ethernet driver in the Raspi OS such that it is not compatible with 10Mbps hardware.
Is there a patch for this fault? I saw mention of using a different bootloader, but where is this and why is it not already in  the November 2024 build? How can i patch this faulty ethernet driver?

I suspect your Pi & router are negotiating 100Mbps.
You can verify this with sudo ethtool  eth0.
You can force a lower speed sudo ethtool -s eth0 speed 10.
If it was me I would just junk the 10Mbps switch; 100Mbps switches are cheap and frankly your WiFi connection would be faster.

ethtool may not be included in standard Raspberry Pi OS but can be installed with apt.

Thanks, I did not know about ethtool. But it reports negotiation speed of the correct 10 Mbps via the old switch on end0 (the ethernet device name on armgian Rpi5). Deliberately forcing the speed to 10 as suggested does not change the ethtool end0 result. In both cases the 10 Mbps connection gives >80% packet loss still. There is no packet loss on this line when I use my orangepi PC, LibrePi, Pine rockpro64, Ryzen 3 suse 15.2 or windows systems. Seems to be specific to the Rpi5, both the 32 and 64 bit versions of RaspiOS and also Armbian -ubuntu-noble for RPi5.

One other cause of loss/slowdown is mismatched Duplex mode.
